# Python R Как удалить строки в CSV файле по аналогичному значению столбца другого CSV файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Имеем 2 файла (CSV или XLSX):
1:

```
id;s1;s2;s3;s4
1111;0;1;2;3
2222;0;2;3;4
3333;0;3;3;3
4444;1;1;1;1
5555;0;0;1;2
6666;0;1;3;4
```

2:

```
id;s1;s2;s3;s4
6666;1;1;3;4
1111;1;1;2;2
4444;0;0;2;3
5555;0;0;1;2
```

Нужно получить 3 файл:

```
id;s1;s2;s3;s4
2222;0;2;3;4
3333;0;3;3;3
```

Иначе говоря из 1 файла нужно удалить строки с встречающимися id файла 2 и записать остаток в 3 файл.
Пытался через сравнение строк решить задачу, но как потом выяснил после id строки не идентичны и способ не сработал. Через pandas нет опыта вычитать строки по столбцам.
Ещё иными словами - нужно найти повторяющиеся значения в столбцах id 1 и 2 файлов и удалить строчки с этими id в 1 файле.

Answer (score 1):

Недавно же был похожий вопрос.

Просто делаете инверсивную маску по индексу:

```
res = df1[~df1.index.isin(df2.index)]
```

res:

```
      s1  s2  s3  s4
id                  
2222   0   2   3   4
3333   0   3   3   3
```

Comment: спасибо, на первый взгляд задача решена, но при детальном анализе он рандомно из первого датафрейма вычел количество строк второго датафрейма, а необходимо было не рандомно вычитать, а по повторяющимся во втором датафрейме значения в столбце id. Или это я неверно что-то сделал?

Comment: Приведите ваши данные, с которыми произошла ошибка.